# Virtualbox getting private IP instead of IP from DHCP server

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, ip, dhcp, windows-server-2012

new to server administration, going through a course on Youtube about Windows Server 2012/Active Directory/etc. I am trying to use Virtualbox to emulate multiple computer systems on the network to form a lab that is connected to my actual Windows server.

My server computer is a Lenovo (10.0.2.3) running Windows Server 2012 with DHCP, DNS and AD DS services, connected to a router (Netgear / 10.0.2.1) which is then connected to my ISP modem/router (Xfinity / 10.0.0.1) I am using Virtualbox on my main laptop (Dell) to run Windows 10 Professional and Windows 7 Professional so I can join them to the domain. Although I've done this successfully, I now can't seem to get a proper internet connection via a Bridged Adapter on my VMs. ipconfig on both machines show that they are getting assigned private IP addresses. So DHCP isn't working for some reason?

This seems to be a bigger issue in Windows 7, where after joining the network I can't login to the computer because "No logon servers available." assumingly due to the loss of internet connectivity.

On my server under DHCP, I seem to receive error 1046 whenever restarting the services: The DHCP/BINL Service on the local machine, belonging to the windows Administrative domain site.com has determined that it is not authorized to start. It has stopped servicing clients." One of the things listed as a possible reason is another DHCP server running, but I've already disabled the one in the Netgear router. Manually authorizing the DHCP server either doesn't help or the server is already authorized.

Something a bit interesting that may help: occasionally in the DHCP MMC, my server shows up as server.site.com occasionally OR some form of private IP address, 169.254.254.254 I think.

The ipconfig of Windows 10 VM:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : WINDOWS10VM
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : site.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : site.com

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-BB-CA-0B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a9dc:4efc:a94a:3abe%5(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.58.190(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.3
                                       10.0.2.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 84410407
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-01-3F-D3-08-00-27-BB-CA-0B
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Change the Network type from NAT to bridged.

Comment: @LPChip both VMs are on bridged connections. what's weird is after I fiddled with this all last night and this morning, all of a sudden the DHCP server started working and gave proper credentials to the VMs right after I posted this. I have a feeling it will break again.

Comment: If it breaks again, it may be at the DHCP end.